# Does Crashlytics log file contain logs when app relaunched from Background Execution?

Tags: ios, background, crash, crashlytics, relaunch

In the fabric crash logs I can see some records from functions which calls from background:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

The Fabric docs says that logs will be retrieved when user manually relaunched the app but before this the app can be relaunched automatically by the Background Execution and related functions can add more logs after crash. Is it correct?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Sorry, I'm not quite following your question. Do you mean if you log within the completion handler on a background execution will be added to the crash report?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Yes, but after when the app was crashed. The background execution can relaunch app if it was crashed. I can see the logs before crash and logs after crash from the background execution functions. They separated by one expected crash log which should be the last record in the file.

Comment: Gotcha, no, that's not supported by the SDK.

Comment: Yes, it's not a part of the Crashlytics SDK. I am saying if your developers saw that the functions from the Background Execution does the app relaunch after CRASH - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57.

Comment: We don't force the app to relaunch post crash, not sure if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, iOS can force app relaunch. The iOS docs says that the app is not relaunch if it was force-quit by the user but I'am not sure if its true in the CRASH case?

Comment: Apps are not relaunched if force-quit by user or if a crash occurs.